# MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts not found

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect AWS RDS with workbench on my machine. For that I'm passing these Inputs:

**SSH Hostname:** **ec2-52-27-226-'''.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com** Public DNS of Instance

**SSH Name:** **ec2-User** Though I am not sure what this should be

**SSH Password**: Don't know which password it should be so blank as of now.

**SSH KeyFile**: .pem file generated through key pair

**MYSql HostName:** **''''''''''''''''.cyexlbt2grsw.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com** DB instance endpoint

**MySql ServerPort: 3306**

**Username:** DB instances master username

**Password:** DB instances master password

After passing these values when I try to connect. Connection fails. Log file of MySQL says:

```
08:18:19 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Starting tunnel
08:18:19 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
08:18:19 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to ec2-52-27-226-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
08:18:20 [WRN][sshtunnel.py:_connect_ssh:293]: IOError, probably caused by file C:\Users\''''''\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts not found, the message was: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Roaming\\MySQL\\Workbench\\ssh\\known_hosts'
08:18:30 [ERR][     SSH tunnel]: TunnelManager.wait_connection got IOError: IO Error: timed out.
 Please refer to logs for details.
08:18:30 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:235]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\sshtunnel.py", line 303, in _connect_ssh
    look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key, timeout=SSH_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 292, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 270, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 292, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\Python\Lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
timeout: timed out
```

Can you please tell what is this issue esp. **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts'**

There is no such folder ssh and file known_hosts in workbench folder.
and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest mistake here was There were three options to connect with workbench

1. By Creating new database connection in the workbench or
2. MySQL Commandline.
3. windows command line.

I tried with first and second not third. I still don't know why they were not getting connected through this two. But when I did with third, it started working on workbench also. But on MySQL command line still don't know correct commands.

How I did with windows command line

```
1. Open cmd

2. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE> dir mysql.*/s

3. Check if there is mySQL.exe if yes go ahead else go till path of mySQL.exe

4. Further pass mysql -h <endpoint> -P <port number> -u <master username> -p

5. You will be asked to fill master password

6. here you go you are connected now.
```

Now try in workbench as well it will get connected.

In addition to this in security group of EC2 Console, provide inbound and outbound authorizations.